Win10 does not boot in any mode after hardware upgrade
Historic system state:
Once there was an HDD with Win7, which had created a 100Mb hidden system partition at the beginning of the disk. After PC upgrade the new Win10 was installed on a new SSD drive, but it appears it kept using BCD data located in that hidden partition - it was only able to boot by selecting old HDD drive as boot device in BIOS, not SSD, but I was ok with that.
Recently I've upgraded PC hardware again and decided to replace old HDDs with new bigger one. But that would remove the boot partition along with the disk. The plan was to use live GParted USB to shrink the only partition on SSD by 100Mb, move it to the right and copy hidden boot partition from old HDD to SSD. Then the usual procedure with Win10 recovery USB, bootrec /fixmbr /fixboot should have restored system's ability to boot. Reliable plan, eh?
Still, it partially worked. 4.5 hours to resize the SSD partition, then 5 seconds to copy hidden partition. Then I fumbled around recovery command line, restored MBR and recreated BCD until at least the loader started working - it showed up Windows logo and a spinning dots circle. Then it was black screen with spinning dots forever, with occasional sparks of SSD LED activity.
What I've tried so far:

unplugged all other drives, including those with additional Program Files folders - some big installations did not fit on a 256Gb SSD.

diskpart -> list volume: shows two primary partitions on SSD


Volume 0    C   System Rese NTFS    Partition   100MB   Healthy
Volume 1    D               NTFS    Partition   238GB   Healthy


bcdedit /enum:

Windows Boot Manager
--------------------
identifier              {bootmgr}
device                  partition=C:
path                    \bootmgr
description             Windows Boot Manager
locale                  en-US
default                 {default}
displayorder            {default}
timeout                 10

Windows Boot Loader
-------------------
identifier              {default}
device                  partition=D:
path                    \WINDOWS\system32\winload.exe
description             Windows 10 Pro 
locale                  en-US
osdevice                partition=D:
systemroot              \Windows
resumeobject            {22845d65-b58d-11ef-b0f7-806e6f6e6963}
bootmenupolicy          Standard
bootlog                 Yes


no restore points available, no system images either

advanced options - startup repair: startup repair couldn't repair your PC.
D:\Windows\System32\LogFiles\Srt\Srttrail.txt contents: Number of root causes = 1, 0 errors, Boot status indicates that the OS booted successfully.

sfc /scannow: runs until 100% without problems, but then says "Windows Resource Protection could not perform the requested operation."
Later it started saying "Windows Resource protection found integrity violations", but it is impossible to use /offlogfile option with commands like /scannow or /verifyonly (when I do that it shows usage instruction instead), so I can neither find out which files are damaged, nor repair them automatically
When I try to do /scanfile or /verifyfile it says "Windows Resource Protection could not perform the requested operation"

dism /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth   - doesn't work, DISM does not support servicing Windows PE with the /online option (because I'm running it from live usb)

dism /image:D:\ /cleanup-image /restorehealth /scratchdir:D:\Windows\temp /logpath:D:\dism.log   - version 10.0.19041.844, image version 10.0.19045.5131, the restore operation completed successfully, the operation completed sucessfully.

bcdedit /set {default} bootlog yes   - sets the flag. Also removed ntbtlog.txt in d:\Windows. New ntbtlog.txt has a lot of BOOTLOG_NOT_LOADED lines.

booting into Safe Mode (option 4): does not boot, stuck in the same black screen; same for other safe mode options

removed d:\hiberfil.sys just in case I sent it into sleep mode before upgrading instead of turning off properly.

smartctl -ax /dev/sdd (SSD)      - run from GParted live usb; 0 reallocation sectors, 0 other bad values, error log empty, extended comprehensive error log contains 7 errors(different LBA, different r/w operations) over 17302 hours of work (720 days) - probably related to my abrupt power downs during repairs, tried running short self-test which should've taken 2 minutes. an hour later it still showed "Self-test routine in progress 50%". Overall-health self-assessment test result: passed.

chkdsk d:        - found no problems, but failed to transfer logged messages to the event log with status 6.


===
Conclusion: SSD is probably good, Windows somehow is not. The only option left to restore Windows is a new installation, that will ruin all settings. Anything I'm missing?

Boot issues are always simple to resolve since Windows booting is a straightforward process - you've done a lot of work and put forth a  lot of effort, however much of it was unnecessary =] simplest solution is to start fresh - boot to WinRE/WinPE, format the boot partition via diskpart (there should only be one boot partition on the drive Windows is installed on, all others delete), then: bootrec /fixmbr && bootrec /fixboot && bootrec /rebuildbcd (the last command is what was being missed). Once done, reboot.

(Cont'd...) Order of partitions should always be: Boot/EFI (BUIS/UEFI), MSR (UEFI-only), OS, WinRE. Since WinRE is only moved to it's own partition on clean installs of Windows 10, it'll need to be manually done. It's recommended to move user data directories (e.g. %UserProfile%\Documents, %UserProfile%\Downloads, etc.) to their own partition via the folder Properties Location tab, and once done, the maximum size of the OS partition need not be >300GB and will work fine on a 256GB SSD.

It is indeed simple, but that only fixes boot process up to winloader.exe and I already did that and it works. But somehow during this process my Windows installation got corrupted and I can not restore it - this is the main problem. Unnecessary work was to verify whether it is in fact corruption and whether it happened due to SSD failure or not.

Are you using sfc from WinRE/WinPE using the /offbootdir and /offwindir options to scan the OS partition's %WinDir% and not WinRE's/WinPE's (this explains how sfc and the Component Store works). If so, please post the contents of the %WinDir%\Logs\CBS\CBS.log (both the OS' and WinPE's please). Worst case scenario would be to temporarily install Windows on a different empty partition, then use Dism and Sfc to repair the offline original install (at some point, Dism's offline /RestoreHealth began failing in WinPE/WinRE)

sfc /scannow without other parameters indeed had checked the WinRE, thats why it was successful. With /offbootdir and /offwindir options sfc fails with "Windows Resource Protection could not perform the requested operation". sfc log is here: https://pastebin.com/rW3xj2jh

I'd clean install Windows at that point - in general, upgrading from one iteration of Windows to a new one isn't preferred and will create issues when going from any iteration <10 to 10 or 11 since drivers for Win 7 & 8 aren't compatible with 10 or 11 (some will cause BSODs), and since there's no way to remove those OEM drivers because they're never intended to be uninstalled, it's always recommended to clean install

Upgrade Windows versions has been vastly improved for more than a decade. Your jump of Windows 7 to Windows 10, if you ran it as an upgrade, was probably a bit too big a jump, and it seems you're dealing with a variety of issues that a clean install would have avoided. In general, going between close versions (7-8, 8-10, 10-11) has a very high success rate. However, your issues are compounded by the drive change. You don't give much detail about the steps you made in the two upgrades you mention though, and that does leave us with a lot of questions.
